# Can't change the backgroundColor of a UILabel in a Static Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a table view with static cells.  In there I have selected the Style `Right Detail`.

Now I would like to change the background colour of the `Detail` label on the right-hand side.  Even though it's just a label, I'm not able to change the background colour in IB.

So I pulled it into a View Controller to do it programmatically.

```
@IBOutlet weak var ukPremiumLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ukPremiumLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 159/255, blue: 184/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
}
```

I also tried it this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ukPremiumLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

I'm not sure why it remains white.

[image]

Comment: Try it. You will be surprised. It ignores it entirely, as it does it programmatically too.  It seems the `detailTextLabel` is somehow overridden.  The accepted solution works though.

Comment: Right, I see now. It’s because you used a built in style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using built-in `UITableViewCell` style, so `backgroundColor` of cell's `detailTextLabel` is somehow overridden after cell is created.

You can solve it by changing this color property after it's been already changed.

To do that, you can change this color inside overridden `willDisplay` method of your `UITableViewController`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if cell.detailTextLabel == ukPremiumLabel {
        ukPremiumLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should I use willdisplay delegate? Instead of cellforrow?

Comment: @ktrkathir If you're using static cells, you don't have to use `cellForRowAt` method for anything, so its easier to change it inside `willDisplay` (you would have to get reference for cell, in `willDisplay` you have reference for cell as parameter of method). Also `willDisplay` is perfect for making "cosmetic" changes (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IBDesignable/IBInspectable` annotations for `UILabel`,

```
@IBDesignable
class BackgroundLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable var persistentBackgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
        didSet {
            super.backgroundColor = persistentBackgroundColor
        }
    }

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if backgroundColor != persistentBackgroundColor {
                backgroundColor = persistentBackgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in `UITableViewCell` assign the `BackgroundLabel` for the `detailTextLabel`,

[image]